# How to set color for some graph's vertex?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I defined graph and got this visualization

```
AdjacencyGraph[
{Labeled[v1, "1"],
 Labeled[v2, "2"],
 Labeled[v3, "3"],
 Labeled[v4, "4"],
 Labeled[v5, "5"],
 Labeled[v6, "6"],
 Labeled[v7, "7"],
 Labeled[v8, "8"],
 Labeled[v9, "9"],
 Labeled[v10, "10"]},
 {{0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
  {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
  {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
  {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0}}]
```

[image]

How I can set other color for vertices 1,2,3,5?

Comment: Use the option `VertexStyle -> {v1 | v2 | v3 | v5 -> Red}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AdjacencyGraph[{Labeled[v1, "1"], Labeled[v2, "2"], Labeled[v3, "3"],
Labeled[v4, "4"], Labeled[v5, "5"], Labeled[v6, "6"], 
Labeled[v7, "7"], Labeled[v8, "8"], Labeled[v9, "9"], 
Labeled[v10, "10"]}, {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0}}, VertexStyle -> {v1 | v2 | v3 | v5 -> Red}]
```

or

```
AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0}}, , VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript["", i], {i, 
10}], VertexStyle -> {1 | 2 | 3 | 5 -> Red}]
```

[image]

Thanks for @kglr